# best way to Reset radio button fields on selecting another one

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar

i have 3 radio buttons, 
1.search by date
2.search by month
3.search by year
and when one clicks on one radio button it shows a html calendar to choose date/month/year.

how to reset the calendar values of other options on selecting some other radio button?

HTML part goes like

```
<input type="radio" name="search" id="byDate"> 
<label for="byDate">search by date</label>           
<div class="reveal-if-active">        
    <input type="date" name="calendar"  ><br>    
</div>

<input type="radio" name="search" id="byMonth">  
<label for="byMonthT">search by Month</label>          
<div class="reveal-if-active" >        
     <input type="date" name="calendar"  ><br>    
</div>

<input type="radio" name="search" id="byYear" > 
<label for="byYear">search by Year</label>
<div class="reveal-if-active">        
    <input list="year" name = "syear">
     <datalist id = "byYear">
     <option value="2016"> 
     <option value="2017">
     <option value="2018>
     </datalist>
 </div>
```

and CSS part goes like

```
.reveal-if-active {
 opacity: 0;
 max-height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-size: 16px;
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
 transform: scale(0.8);
 -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
 transition: 0.5s;
 }

 input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .reveal-if-active,
 input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .reveal-if-active
 input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .reveal-if-active {
 opacity: 1;
 max-height: 100px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 transform: scale(1);
 overflow: visible;
}
```

suppose i select "search by date" first and enter some value there. i want to get that value cleared when i choose "search by month".

Comment: They must have same `name`

Comment: i got that. but i have some other issues. please see the code.

Answer (score 1):

Give them the same name.

```html
<input type="radio" name="test" value="val1">test1
<br>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="val1">test2
<br>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="val1">test3
```